# Aerospike, NodeJS. Pushing into array in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, aerospike

I need to push some data in array, that stored in object
Example.
Bin, that I get

```
db.get(key) // -> { a: 'b', b: { c: [] } }
```

I need to push into `b.c`, but I can't, because of error

```
db.operate(key, [Aerospike.lists.append('b.c', 1)]) // -> AerospikeError: no operations defined
```

Can it be solved or I can't do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @pgupta correctly pointed out, you need to set the CDT context to operate on nested lists/maps. With the Node.js client, you use the [ListOperation#withContext](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/module-aerospike_lists-ListOperation.html#withContext) function to set the context:

```
db.put(key, { a: 'b', b: { c: [] } })
db.operate(key, [
  Aerospike.lists.append('b', 1)
    .withContext((ctx) => ctx.addMapKey('c'))
])
db.get(key) // => { a: 'b', b: { c: [1] } }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to use Complex Data Types (CDT) Contexts - CTX class in my Java example. This requires Aerospike server version 4.6.0.2 or higher.

For example, I have a record with a bin having data like so:

```
KEY_ORDERED_MAP('{"l1k1":{"l2k1":{"l3k1":31, "l3k2":32, "l3k3":99}, "l2k2":22, "l2k3":23}, "l1k2":12, "l1k3":13}')
```

Using Java, (I don't have node.js example for you. (EDITED) --> Node.js api reference for maps is [here](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/module-aerospike_maps-MapOperation.html#withContext) -- search CDTContext in API reference -- List example is added in 2nd answer below by @jan-hecking).  I want to replace "l3k3":99, int value with an ordered list, with no duplicates in the list, I can do:

```
//Edit 2nd level nested value l3k3:99 to an empty list type
           //Note: This list type is inserted with default list policies (UNORDERED)

            List<Value> l1 = new ArrayList<Value>();

            client.operate(wPolicy, key1,
                           MapOperation.put(
                           mPolicy, "myMap", Value.get("l3k3"), Value.get(l1),
                           CTX.mapKey(Value.get("l1k1")),
                           CTX.mapKey(Value.get("l2k1"))
                           )
                          );

           //Append items directly to nested list at l3k3

            l1.add(Value.get(0));
            l1.add(Value.get(4));
            l1.add(Value.get(1));
            l1.add(Value.get(4));

            ListPolicy lPolicy = new ListPolicy(ListOrder.ORDERED,
                                 ListWriteFlags.ADD_UNIQUE|ListWriteFlags.NO_FAIL|ListWriteFlags.PARTIAL);
            client.operate(wPolicy, key1,
                           //We need to explicitly change the order from UNORDERED to ORDERED
                           ListOperation.setOrder("myMap", ListOrder.ORDERED,
                           CTX.mapKey(Value.get("l1k1")),
                           CTX.mapKey(Value.get("l2k1")),
                           CTX.mapKey(Value.get("l3k3"))
                           ),
                           ListOperation.appendItems(
                           lPolicy, "myMap", l1,
                           CTX.mapKey(Value.get("l1k1")),
                           CTX.mapKey(Value.get("l2k1")),
                           CTX.mapKey(Value.get("l3k3"))
                           )
                          );
```

This yields:

```
KEY_ORDERED_MAP('{"l1k1":{"l2k1":{"l3k1":31, "l3k2":32, "l3k3":[0, 1, 4]}, "l2k2":22, "l2k3":23}, "l1k2":12, "l1k3":13}')
```